# The Request parameter for views function in Django greys out

Tags: django

No matter what I try in vs code the request is always greyed out. I'm following the Django tutorial and I get a 404 when loading the server because the index function can't be called cause the parameter is greyed, This works perfectly fine in Pycharm, but not vs code. Any solutions?

```
def index(request): 
return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

## this is the urls for polls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =  [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

## And urls for the whole website

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: The greyed parameter in your IDE doesn't mean the function isn't getting called.
It's just a hint that the parameter isn't being used by the function. You'll need to show your `urls` too, and how you're trying to access the view.

Comment: I added the `urls`

Answer (score 0):

The grayed out 'request' parameter in your function does not mean that it isn't called, it's telling you that the parameter isn't used, also make sure you use indentation in your function views:

```
def index(request): 
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```